# How to load a number of 2 bytes pointed by X to a register in AVR?

Tags: assembly, memory, avr

There is the LD instruction, and I can use LD Rd,X to load the value which is pointed by X into Rd, but all the registers are of  1 byte, what if the data pointed by X  is of 2 bytes? Is it automatically loaded to the next register? For example if I write LD R21,X then the value will be store in R21 - R20?

Comment: Of course not. How would the cpu know when to load 2 bytes? You just load the two bytes separately.

Comment: like this:
 LD R21,X+ 
 and then 
 LD R20,X
?

Comment: That just increments X register after the load, it still only loads 1 byte. You need to do something like `LD R20, X+; LD R21, X+`

Comment: Thanks man, I'll try it that way!